# Propose changes to the FAQ

Tags: discussion, support

Checking out the FAQ and what new users normally miss when posting a question, I was wondering if it was possible to improve the FAQ to include some of the following:

- Rule to always include what Ubuntu version the OP is using if it applies (Most times it does)
- Rule to include the hardware (And in some cases the specific model) the user is using if it applies (For cases where hardware is the problem or some configuration related to it)
- More emphasis on how to Accept an answer, add a tag or use the auto complete part when typing the title of the question. Some users simply get lost in that part.
- Priority to have "First search in Askubuntu for your question before posting it". Most do not even search, the just go ahead and create the question. Also in the FAQ, the first part does not mention searching but goes on first explaining how to create the question. I think in my opinion, that it should first mention the search option to the user (move it up instead of having it at the end and making sure the user understands that it is more probable that his/her question already exists in Askubuntu), since most questions are already answered. A second part about this is a HOW TO use the search option in Askubuntu, including how to search for specific tags or keywords.
- Send first time users to the FAQ when they want to create a question, so at least they can read some of the rules. (Do not know if this is already applied)

This might not be all, but the FAQ is in need of some love, specially beginner's love.

Comment: I think a lot of this is important to getting questions answered. +1  Its annoying how often you have to ask this stuff :/

Answer (score 4):

New users get a message box, with several bullet points that already have this information and a link to the FAQ. Unfortunately we don't control the entire FAQ, merely the top section. I have a few issues with the first two of your bullets. Version of Ubuntu you're using isn't actually *that* important, neither is hardware for the most part. In fact I think those details only apply to a small subset of the questions asked on the site.

With that, I agree with your next point: accepting answers isn't that obvious at first. However, the site also helps users understand that by popping up boxes from time to time to remind the user to accept an answer (for instance if an asker upvotes an answer they'll get a popup saying "Did this answer your question? If so please accept it as the answer").

The site searches questions as you type in the Title box when asking a new question for duplicates. The fact that people don't heed those warnings and that information leads in to my last point.

You can lead a horse to water but you can't get it to drink.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Marco, appreciate it. Anyway, next time, I'll drown the horse. Let's see if he doesn't drink by then.. muhahaha.

Comment: Ha! I know how you feel, it can be frustrating at time for sure.

Comment: Maybe when the API gets write access for posts, there will be a Ubuntu app that basically forces water into the horse.

Answer (score 1):

The changes I propose:

- Adding the following text:

> - When asking a question, please make sure to include your version of Ubuntu, and your hardware specifications if you are having trouble with something related to hardware, video, or networking.
> - Please tag your question with a set of [tags](https://askubuntu.com/tags) that help describe the problem you are facing in order to categorize it to be easily found. For example, [12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/12.04) [nvidia](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/nvidia) [xrandr](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/xrandr) is better than [12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/12.04) [freeze](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/freeze). You can search for tags on the [tags page](https://askubuntu.com/tags) or when asking a question.
>
>   [image: Searching for tags while asking a question]
> - Before asking a question, please [search](https://askubuntu.com/search) and make sure it hasn't been answered already. Remember that some problems can be described in more than one set of words, like "Graphics hangs after startup" as well as "Video freezes once booted". If your question is a duplicate, it will most likely be closed.
> - Once you have found an answer to your question, please mark your question as solved  using the grey checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you best.
>
>   [image: The accept answer button on an answer]

Images are coming...

Comment: +1 I like it. Very simple and to the point.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado How's it with images? Are the images distracting or not useful? I jus need some feedback.

Comment: Very nice indeed and very helpful buddy. This is what I had in mind. BTW somebody gave you a -1 ???

Comment: Indeed. You got a +2-1, i have a +1-1.

Comment: Lol. Let's see who gt more negatives then ^^